# What is the type of a derived class stored in a base class variable in c#

Tags: c#, decorator, derived-class

Suppose I have this code:

```
BaseClass baseClassVar = new DerivedClass();
baseClassVar.OverloadingMethod();
```

Both `BaseClass` and `DerivedClass` have one method called `OverloadingMethod`.

If we create an instance of `DerivedClass` and store it in a `BaseClass` variable; then call `OverloadingMethod`, it will call the method in base class.

If so we can assume `baseClassVar` is a type of `BaseClass`, and it does sounds logical. But viewing the object in debug or call `GetType()` actually return a type of `DerivedClass`. How does it work like that?

Comment: Your `OverloadingMethod()` is **not virtual**, in this case there is no vtable entry then you call `BaseClass.OverloadingMethod()` if you have a variable of type `BaseClass` and `DerivedClass.OverloadingMethod()` if you have a variable of type `DerivedClass`. Odd situation you should almost never have in real world (and compiler should emit a warning CS0108 for that unless you explicitly mark it with `new`).

Comment: This is standard magic in any object-oriented programming language.  More obvious when you write `object obj = new DerivedClass();`.  Any object reference can be converted to a base class reference.  Crystal ball says that you need to lookup `virtual` in your favorite C# language book, overloading means something completely different.

Comment: Accepted answer from linked question contains good explanation about `virtual`/`new` methods.

Comment: I know how to use virtual and overriding to resolve this. I just curious why `GetType()` return `DerivedClass`? If we know it's type is `DerivedClass`, why don't point to the new overloading method, rather than pointing back to base method?